# How to set condition for single option of ansible module alone

Tags: conditional-statements, jinja2, ansible

Is that possible to set conditions for a single option of the ansible module.

```
   Using set_fact we can set condition aand use that variable in the ansible module. Alternatively is there any other option to set the condition using if loop in jinja or something like that.
```

E.g:

```
 - name: Simple PUT operation
   s3:
     bucket: mybucket
     object: /my/desired/key.txt
     src: /usr/local/myfile.txt
     mode: put
```

I  want to **add s3_url option** if it satifies the condition sample_var= myapp.If it doesnot satify it wont have to add s3_url

```
   - name: Simple PUT operation
     s3:
       bucket: mybucket
       object: /my/desired/key.txt
       src: /usr/local/myfile.txt
       mode: put 
       s3_url: "s3my url"------if it satisfies sample_var=myapp
```

How can i use  jinja here when it satisfies my condition it needs to add this option to the ansible module?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to read about [omitting parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters):

```
- name: Simple PUT operation
  s3:
    bucket: mybucket
    object: /my/desired/key.txt
    src: /usr/local/myfile.txt
    mode: put 
    s3_url: "{{ 's3my_url' if sample_var == 'myapp' else omit }}"
```

Comment: suppose we are setting conditions inside like this                                s3_url: "{{ 's3my_url' if {{ sample_var }}  == {{ myapp }}  else omit }}", it doesnot execute. When setting the conditions.how can we handle such conditions???

Comment: The syntax is exactly as I posted, don't use nested braces. If `myapp` is a variable and not a literal string, use `myapp` without single quotes.